# Passing blocks in methods of JSConext

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I'm using JSContext and create a function like below

```
context[@"callOriginalMethod"] = ^(NSArray* arr, closureBlock block)
{
    block(arr);
};
```

and closureBlock is defined as

```
typedef void (^closureBlock)(NSArray*);
```

However, when I call `callOriginalMethod` from JS, I get this error:
`TypeError: callOriginalMethod is not a function. (In 'callOriginalMethod(a, globalCl)', 'callOriginalMethod' is an instance of NSBlock)`

When I remove the `closureBlock block` from `callOriginalMethod` everything works as expected. What is the issue and how can we fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
context[@"callBlock"] = ^(JSValue *block)
{
    [closure callWithArguments:nil];
};
```

and in JS

`callBlock(a, function(a){closure(a);})`